# First sqLite database: trying to add integers to database

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite

So I'm trying to create my first `sqLite` database. It's something very simple. All I need is for it to have one column that only contains integers. The integers I want to add are from `putExtra` from an intent. I also want to be able to add and remove integers from the table. I've been trying to follow some videos on you-tube to accomplish this but I cannot figure it out.

Heres my **MbDbHandler** code

```
package com.example.zach.listview;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContentValues;

public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "checked_routes.db";
public static final String TABLE_CHECKED_ROUTES = "checked_routes";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_checkedRoutes";

public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name,     SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "CREATE_TABLE " + TABLE_CHECKED_ROUTES + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY " + ");";

    db.execSQL(query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP_TABLE_IF_EXISTS " + TABLE_CHECKED_ROUTES);
    onCreate(db);
}

/////Add row to table
public void addCheckedRoute(CheckedRoutes checkedRoute){

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_ID, checkedRoute.get_checkedRoute());
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_CHECKED_ROUTES, null, values);
    db.close();
}

////Delete row from table
public void deleteCheckedRow(int checkedRoute){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_CHECKED_ROUTES + "WHERE " + COLUMN_ID     + "=\"" + checkedRoute + "\";" );
}
}
```

heres my **CheckedRoutes** class for the db

```
package com.example.zach.listview;


public class CheckedRoutes {

int _checkedRoute;

public void set_checkedRoute(int _checkedRoute){
    this._checkedRoute = _checkedRoute;
}

public int get_checkedRoute(){
    return _checkedRoute;
}
}
```

and here in my `adapter class` where i'm trying to use the db.

```
MyDBHandler dbHandler;
dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);

 int listViewItemPosition = ((Activity) getContext()).getIntent().getIntExtra("listViewItemPosition",0);

       CheckedRoutes checkedRoute = new CheckedRoutes(listViewItemPosition);
        dbHandler.addCheckedRoute(checkedRoute);
```

but I'm getting an error saying

> CheckedRoutes() CheckedRoutes cannot be applied to int on my listViewItemPosition.

I just don't think I've set up the database correctly to take in int values.

Any help would be appreciated thank you!

Comment: You're getting the error duo to the fact that listViewItemPosition is not an int.
as CheckedRoutes constructor takes an int..

Comment: why `listViewItemPosition` is not an int...there is a problem in calling constructor..@skyw00lker

Comment: `.getIntExtra("listViewItemPosition",0)` would return an integer only..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mistakes I found in your code

- In `onCreate` and `onUpgrade` methods of Handler class. **You're executing wrong SQL Queries.**

  ```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CHECKED_ROUTES + "(" +
          COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY " + ");";

      db.execSQL(query);
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
      db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CHECKED_ROUTES);
      onCreate(db);
  }
  ```

Don't use underscore character in between.

- **Also check `CheckedRoutes` does not have parameterised constructor**, so change declaration of `CheckedRoutes` as follows

  ```
  CheckedRoutes checkedRoute = new CheckedRoutes();
  ```

and set value for `_checkedRoute` as follows

```
checkedRoute.set_checkedRoute(listViewItemPosition);
```

Hope it'll help.

Comment: thanks I tried the above code but when I use .set_checkedRoute I get cannot resolve method .set_checkedRoute. Edit: nvm its working now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can u please check whether this constructor exist? I couldn't find any

```
  CheckedRoutes checkedRoute = new CheckedRoutes(listViewItemPosition);
```